# packer option to avoid warning while shell provisioning

Tags: linux, shell, packer

Is there a way to avoid warning while doing packer shell provisioning. My packer build exits with this warning:

> googlecompute:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/*vendor/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:160:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>       googlecompute: InsecurePlatformWarning
>   ==> googlecompute: Deleting instance...
>       googlecompute: Instance has been deleted!
>   ==> googlecompute: Deleting disk...
>       googlecompute: Disk has been deleted! Build 'googlecompute' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1

Answer (score 1):

That's not a warning, it's an error.

You could suppress it by forcing your script to exit with 0. But you probably want to fix the error instead.

If you provide your script i can give more detailed guidance.